# How To Install Redis On macOS Sierra Public Beta

Tags: node.js, redis, homebrew

I am attempting to install Redis using Homebrew for an app project. Homebrew IS installed and has been updated to its latest version. However, when I run `$ brew install redis` from the terminal, I am always met with the same error message, reposted below.

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ brew install redis
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Downloading http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/oliverisenrich/Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-3.2.3.tar.gz
==> make install PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3 CC=clang
Last 15 lines from /Users/oliverisenrich/Library/Logs/Homebrew/redis/01.make:
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
make[1]: *** [ae.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [anet.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [dict.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [zmalloc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sds.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [quicklist.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [server.o] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

The error message says gives a warning saying only that support is not offered for my Mac OS X version (10.12), not explicitly that it cannot be installed. However, attempting to run `brew services start redis` returns the following message:

```
➜  nodj git:(JobsPage) ✗ brew services start redis
Service `redis` already started, use `brew services restart redis` to restart.
```

The above leads me to believe it IS installed. And, yet, running `brew info redis` returns

```
➜  nodj git:(JobsPage) ✗ brew info redis
redis: stable 3.2.3, HEAD
Persistent key-value database, with built-in net interface
http://redis.io/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/redis.rb
==> Options
--with-jemalloc
    Select jemalloc as memory allocator when building Redis
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To have launchd start redis now and restart at login:
  brew services start redis
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

Is there any alternative/workaround to getting Redis up and running (preferably without needing to revert to a prior stable OS release:

Answer (score 2):

it's fixed now, you can do:

```
brew update
brew install redis
```

Confirmed working here.

Answer (score 0):

just use this command to start Redis servers:

```
redis-server
```

or

```
sudo redis-server
```

If you want to check the version of Redis, just use this command:

```
redis-cli --version
```

or

```
redis-server --version
```

If your `mac system is too low`. Or if your `Xcode software version is too low`.

Or even if your `homebrew does not support` downloading Nginx (*because homebrew requires you to
upgrade the computer system and Xcode software version, but you don’t want it, you just don’t!*)

Also, if you want to `mannually download Redis`, please reference this:
https://gist.github.com/SofijaErkin/6fa0d09afb062518794528c5e77a748f